# How to make page scoped comet actor in Lift

Tags: scala, comet, lift, actor

We have an event monitor in our project which uses Lift Comet to show real-time events. 
And there is some query-based filtering for it, but the problem is that many monitor's pages opened in browser share same session, so i can't set up event filtering individually - all pages are using same query. Is there any ability to create actors per page, not per session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the 'name' attribute when you instantiate the comet actor on the page. This should result in new actors being instantiated for each name. You can get at the name assigned to an actor through it's 'name' value.

Usually you'll get quicker & better answers on the Lift mailing list. No accuracy guarantees here ;-)

Comment: I need actor being instantiated not each time (request) - but for each page. On the other hand we're using ajax for page interaction - so i can live with it (i think i can have some PageVar with current name to access actor from ajax). Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, that's what I've done in the past. Randomly generate a string in the snippet to use as the comet 'name' attribute for that page. Results in one actor per page/tab.